# When not to use standardization on variables

Tags: standardization

Can someone give me a counter example of when we should not use standardization on variables? I understand what standardization is but i am not getting the point why we need to standardize variables? I seached for many sites but can't find an answer, On many sites i found that we should use it when variables are measured on different scales.
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What algorithms need feature scaling, beside from SVM?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/244507/what-algorithms-need-feature-scaling-beside-from-svm)