# "Joint" dummy variables for two different variables

Tags: modeling, interaction, categorical-encoding

I am supposed to show the hazard ratio (HR) stratified by gender (1= female vs. 2= male) and age groups (quartiles, 1-4)*. The combination "female" and "first quartile of age" is supposed to be the reference, i.e. having a HR of 1.

The plot should look like that:
[image: How the plot should look like]

Since every group combination (2nd quartile and female, 1st quartile and male,...) is supposed to show the HR in comparison to the refernce (female and 1st quartile of age group), I am wondering whether I can firstly code both variables as one joint variable and afterwards make dummy variables (D1- D7) out of it like that:

```
Age groups   Gender    Joint variable   D1   D2   D3   D4   D5   D6   D7
(quartiles)  (1=f,2=m)
1            1         1                0    0    0    0    0    0    0
1            2         2                1    0    0    0    0    0    0
2            1         3                0    1    0    0    0    0    0
2            2         4                0    0    1    0    0    0    0
3            1         5                0    0    0    1    0    0    0
3            2         6                0    0    0    0    1    0    0
4            1         7                0    0    0    0    0    1    0
4            2         8                0    0    0    0    0    0    1
```

My idea is to use those dummy variables as predictors in a Cox model. The interpretation of HR= 2 for D7, for example, would be something like "Being old (4th quartile) and male is associated with a twofold risk of mortality versus being young (first quartile) and female". Is this a valid approach? I haven't read about cases where a joint dummy coding was used for two different variables and can't find any resource online.

* Notice to the usage of age groups: I know that there are [problems](http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/wiki/Main/CatContinuous) associated with splitting up a continuous variable in groups, but this is what I am supposed to do.

Comment: This seems to be about how to code a calculation -- in some unstated language with no code visible. It's hard to know what kind of answer you expect. Please see advice in the Help Center on software-specific questions, which usually belong elsewhere.

Comment: This question is in no sense about any software. The question is wehter or not this is a valid approach, regardless of the software being used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *joint variable* of two factors is their **interaction** (and that is what you have hand-coded in D1,..., D7.) In `R`, if `Gender` and `Age` are the two factors, this can be done as in the code snippet below:

```r
set.seed(7*11*13) 
Gender <- factor( sample(c("Male", "Female"), 100, replace=TRUE)) 
Age <- factor( sample(c("Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4"), 100, replace=TRUE)) 
table(Gender, Age)
        Age
Gender   Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4
  Female 15  8  8 17
  Male   14 14 11 13
```

Then to make the interactions variable:

```r
mydf <- data.frame(Age=Age, Gender=Gender) 
tab <- model.matrix( ~ (Gender:Age) - 1, mydf)
```

and now you can compare with your manually constructed variable.  See also  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080774/generating-interaction-variables-in-r-dataframes.  This way we have constructed the dummies for the interaction.  Maybe more useful, we can also *construct a new factor variable which codes the interaction*. This is simple:

```r
mydf$D <- with(mydf,  interaction(Age, Gender))
 with(mydf, table(D))
D
Q1.Female Q2.Female Q3.Female Q4.Female   Q1.Male   Q2.Male   Q3.Male   Q4.Male 
       15         8         8        17        14        14        11        13
```

and now `D` can be used directly in formulas.

**EDIT**

As for questions in comments: Yes, you can use the 7 dummies. But logically, the variable is represented by the full set of 8 dummies, and sometimes we want them all. If I replace my code above `~ (Gender:Age) - 1` with `~ (Gender:Age)` then (try it) you will get the 7 dummies, but you will also get the intercept, which was omitted by my code (that is what `-1` does.) See [What algorithms need feature scaling, beside from SVM?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/244507/what-algorithms-need-feature-scaling-beside-from-svm/252625#252625)  for a case where you do not want to drop one dummy!

Comment: Thank you! Why are there 8 dummies for 8 groups in the output of model.matrix(...)? Usually, creating dummies gives you k-1 dummies for a group with k levels and thus my table has only 7 dummies for 8 groups. Interestingly, using lm(rnorm(nrow(mydf)) ~ Age + Gender + Age*Gender, mydf) gives 7 dummies (as I expected) while the analog code for your model.matrix() in lm(rnorm(nrow(mydf)) ~ Age:Gender, mydf) gives 8 dummies. One of the 8 dummies has a NA anyway, so I can simply use the 7 dummies as I described?